# Save shuffled dataset state

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.x

I'm looking for a mechanism to save the random state used by `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle`. For context, I want to be able to reproduce training results across restarts.

I have a solution (given below) but it's not particularly elegant, and I'm fairly confident the `batch` / `unbatch` will lead to performance issues. Is there an equivalent way to do this using `Dataset.shuffle`?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


class Shuffler(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, buffer_size: int, seed: int = 0):
        self._buffer_size = buffer_size
        self._seed = seed
        self._rng = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(seed)

    def __call__(self, dataset: tf.data.Dataset):
        def map_fn(*args):
            vals = self._rng.uniform((self._buffer_size,))
            i = tf.argsort(vals)
            if len(args) == 1:
                (args,) = args
            return tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x: tf.gather(x, i), args)

        return dataset.batch(self._buffer_size).map(map_fn).unbatch()


def as_list(ds: tf.data.Dataset):
    return [x.numpy() for x in ds]


shuffler = Shuffler(5)
chkpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(shuffler=shuffler)
p0 = chkpt.save("/tmp/chkpt-0")
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(5).apply(shuffler)
expected0 = as_list(ds)
p1 = chkpt.save("/tmp/chkpt-1")
expected1 = as_list(ds)
# ensure they're actually shuffled
assert not np.all(expected0 == expected1)
assert set(expected0) == set(expected1)

chkpt.restore(p0)
np.testing.assert_equal(as_list(ds), expected0)

np.testing.assert_equal(as_list(ds), expected1)
# mangle state by iterating over it again
as_list(ds)

# restore p1
chkpt.restore(p1)
np.testing.assert_equal(as_list(ds), expected1)
print("Passed!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the state is already managed in the [Iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Iterator).

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def as_list(it: tf.data.Iterator, length: int = 5):
    return [it.next().numpy() for _ in range(length)]


ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(5).shuffle(5, seed=0).repeat()
it = iter(ds)
chkpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(it=it)
p0 = chkpt.save("/tmp/chkpt-0")
expected0 = as_list(it)
p1 = chkpt.save("/tmp/chkpt-1")
expected1 = as_list(it)
# ensure they're actually shuffled
assert not np.all(expected0 == expected1)
assert set(expected0) == set(expected1)

chkpt.restore(p0)
np.testing.assert_equal(as_list(it), expected0)

np.testing.assert_equal(as_list(it), expected1)
# mangle state by iterating over it again
as_list(it)

# restore p1
chkpt.restore(p1)
np.testing.assert_equal(as_list(it), expected1)
print("Passed!")
```